# How does the Charger feat work with Fighter's Extra Attack feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, fighter

If I have a 5th-level fighter that has the Charger feat, can I take my Extra Attack after using my bonus attack with the Charger feat?

Answer (score 10):

> Beginning at 5th level, you can attack twice, instead of once, whenever you take the Attack action on your turn.

The Extra Attack feature only applies to taking the *Attack action*, which is a specific action you can take on your turn. It doesn't apply every time you attack. It would not allow you to take an extra attack as part of your bonus action from Charger.

Since you have to Dash to use the Charger bonus action, as a 5th-level fighter, you would need an action surge to also benefit from Extra Attack (for a total of three attacks).

Comment: You'd need to spend an action surge to make that work as you have to take the dash action before using the charger feat. I suppose there's also the question of making a single attack, using action surge to dash, moving to another enemy and using the feat to make a bonus action attack before taking your second attack granted by extra attack.